# IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug Maven project - How to pass profiles?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jboss, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I want the Run/Debug option to build my project using two profiles, say *A* and *B*. When manually building I would do:

```
mvn package -PA,B
```

I know I can choose profiles using `View > Tool Window > Maven Projects > Profiles` but it doesn't seem to be passing profiles.

My POM looks something like the following:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <artifactId>my_app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>A</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <some.prop>someValue</some.prop>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>B</id>
            <properties>
                ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${some.prop}</finalName>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
              ...
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would expect the *finalName* to be resolved as `my_app_someValue` (as it would while building manually using command line) but instead it is resolved as `my_app_${some.prop}` which results in  *target/my_app_${some.prop}* directory created.

How can I acheive the above while Running or debugging application?

If it anyhow matters, I am trying to run/debug an application for Jboss.

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to debug a JBoss web application. For the same I have setup a Jboss local server and I have created a run/debug configuration out of the same.

In the same, pre-launch tasks are:

- Build
- Build 'my_app:war exploded' artifact

Answer (score 1):

Using `View > Tool Window > Maven Projects > Profiles` is the correct way to do it. Even if you are not using a maven run config... it still affects your classpath for maven projects.

What type of run/debug config are you running exactly?

I recently asked more or less the same question in the Jetbrains community, you can read it here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000127230-The-impact-of-maven-profiles-on-spring-boot-runner-

Comment: Just to verify the maven integration / project setup... can you create a maven run config with "mvn clean package -PA,B" and see if that does generate the proper file.

Can you also confirm that the compiler output is stored in the target folder?

Comment: Creating a maven config does generate the files and the output is stored in the target folder too.

Comment: Did it generate the correct files? or still with the wrong name

Comment: Correct files. Since I can specify what all profiles to pass in the maven config.

My theory is, Build configuration is actually normal java Build and not a maven build by default. Am I right to assume so?

Comment: Yes, the "normal" build just uses the compiler and doesn't use maven internally. But it can affect your classpath, see the link I added.

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense. What I'm interested in Hot Deploy or Hot Swap without having to redeploy. Current using "update" button it is only able to Hot Swap classes but not resources. It has "update classes and resources" option but it doesn't really update resources like JSP, CSS, JS and all. It's an overkill to run maven command again or re-start run/debug everytime I make a small change. Any idea about how can I improve this process?

Comment: The debug hotswap feature is limited. If you are looking for more sophisticated hotswapping features, you can have a look at JRebel. See this link for the differences: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/comparison-matrix/

Comment: In that comparison, none of the system list resources. And existing JVM Swap (only change to method bodies) works for me. I'm only concerned about resources at the moment. I wonder if it' s a maven thing to copy the resources too.

Comment: although not listed, it does support it... I can find many threads of people who need help with reloading jsp's with jrebel :-)